# Use of an integer code in URIMatcher class in Android

Tags: android

According to the Android Documentation, we have to provide int code for every URI we match.

```
addURI(String authority, String path, int code)
```

and as the documentation explains:

> Add a URI to match, and the code to return when this URI is matched.

What role does the "code" play?

I understand in the case of UriMatcher.NO_MATCH that returns -1, for invalid matches!, but what for the other codes like 1, 20, 14 etc?

For example,

```
private static final int PEOPLE = 1;
private static final int PEOPLE_ID = 2;
private static final int PEOPLE_PHONES = 3;
private static final int PEOPLE_PHONES_ID = 4;
private static final int PEOPLE_CONTACTMETHODS = 7;
```

or 
    `private static final int DELETED_PEOPLE = 20;`

The above code has been taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html).

Answer (score 1):

This code will be returned by [UriMatcher.match()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html#match(android.net.Uri)). Then you can use a switch statement to take action based on the type of the URI which was matched. [Here](https://github.com/BaseballCardTracker/bbct/blob/c79d17113447275668169b53ce4c9f15e89bd60f/gradle/android/src/main/java/bbct/android/common/provider/BaseballCardProvider.java#L82-L112) is an example from my own project.

Comment: Okay is this due to the reason that Java did not support String based switching prior to Java 7? or just a feasible way of doing this?

Comment: @AshishKrishnan Java has always supported switching on `char` variables. I assume you mean the new `String` switching. But to answer your actual question...I don't know why this particular mechanism was chosen. Even with String switching available, an `int` seems like a better identifier because it has less memory overhead.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, I meant `String` .! Thanks! Looks convincing to me!